# In Console I cant find in chrome Application > Cookies > xxx

Tags: javascript

I've found a cookie in *Application > Cookie* in Chrome named "xxx" and I want to see its value in the console. What code do I need to type?

I've tried `document.cookie` and it's not in there.

Comment: `document.cookie.split(';').map(x=>x.trim()).map(x=>x.split('='))`

Answer (score 0):

If you type the following to the console it should give you a string with the contents of the property xxx.

```
document.cookie.match(new RegExp('(^| )xxx=([^;]+)'))[2]
```

Comment: VM5506:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '2' of null
    at <anonymous>:1:78
and i want its value

Comment: This means there is no cookie by the name 'xxx'

Comment: its not in document.cookie its in chrome Application > Cookie websitename

Comment: you should also see the contents of the cookie in there. there should be a column called Value

Comment: i dont understand.

Comment: Note that if your cookie has the `HttpOnly` flag, it won't show up in `document.cookie` and will not be accessible from the console (that's the whole point of the `HttpOnly` flag). The _Application > Cookie_ tab will tell you if this is the case.